# Python typing: best way to annotate parent class return subclass type object

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a BaseClass like follow:

```
class BaseClass:
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, arg1: str) -> BaseClass:
        instance = cls(arg1)
        return instance
```

And a derived class like this:

```
class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, arg: str) -> None:
        self.arg = arg
```

Now when I do

```
data: DerivedClass = DerivedClass.create('first arg)
```

mypy gives following error:

```
"BaseClass" cannot be assigned to declared type "DerivedClass"
"BaseClass" is incompatible with "DerivedClass"
```

How I solve it is by using `typing.cast`

```
data: DerivedClass = cast(
    DerivedClass, 
    DerivedClass.get(derived_class_instance)
)
```

How should i solve it without using `typing.cast`

Answer (score 7):

You can change `BaseClass` to this:

```
T = TypeVar("T")

from typing import TypeVar, Type

class BaseClass:
    @classmethod
    def get(cls: Type[T], instance: T) -> T:
        return instance
```

This forces `instance` to be of the type that the `get` class method is being called on. So `BaseClass.get` takes a `BaseClass` and returns a `BaseClass`, while `DerivedClass.get` takes a `DerivedClass` and returns a `DerivedClass`. Running `mypy` results in:

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Great thanks, that works fine. but when I use cls to instantiate the instance in classmethod it says `BaseClass cannot be instantiated`. Plesse check edits. Sorry for changing the question.

Comment: In that case `mypy` is right. You are assuming that every possible `cls` can be instantiated with a `str`. But only `DerivedClass` can, and `BaseClass` can't, so `BaseClass.create("abc")` would error at runtime. Do you see why mypy rejects your program? @wrufesh

Comment: When cls other properties which we try to access in BaseClass than we get the error like `xyz` attribute not defined. otherwise I am not getting any error now. also adding `T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseClass)` solves attribute problem as well.

Comment: For someone like me that has not fully understood the question either, I would much appreciate an example of how the `get` function is used.